# How to animate an object multiple times with delay in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I want to animate multiple buttons multiple times in succession but when a button is required to animate twice or more, the code doesn't work at all.

```
//function that animates a button
func buttonAnimationChain(buttonColor:UIButton, iDelayTime: Int){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: Double(iDelayTime), options: [],
                   animations: {
                    buttonColor.alpha = 0.0;
    },
                   completion: {finished in
                    buttonColor.alpha = 1.0;
    })

}
//function that displays the sequence
func showSequence(iGeneratedArraySequence: [Int]){

    var iDelayTime:Int = 0;

    for _ in 1 ... iGeneratedArraySequence.count{
        if(iGeneratedArraySequence[iDelayTime] == 1){
            buttonAnimationChain(buttonColor: buttonBlue, iDelayTime: iDelayTime);
        }
        if(iGeneratedArraySequence[iDelayTime] == 2){
            buttonAnimationChain(buttonColor: buttonYellow, iDelayTime: iDelayTime);
        }
        if (iGeneratedArraySequence[iDelayTime] == 3){
            buttonAnimationChain(buttonColor: buttonPurple, iDelayTime: iDelayTime);
        }
        if(iGeneratedArraySequence[iDelayTime] == 4){
            buttonAnimationChain(buttonColor: buttonGreen, iDelayTime: iDelayTime);

        }//end of if statement
            iDelayTime += 1;
    }//end of for loop
}//end of function
```

When the generated array has only numbers that are not repeated, the animation works perfectly but once a button needs to be animated twice, nothing shows up. I think this happens because the button just stays in the inactive state even while another function turns it active and I can't think of a solution to fix this. I've tried using the sleep() function but that just generates wonky results.

Answer (score 0):

```
func buttonAnimationChain(buttonColor:UIButton, index : Int){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 1.0, options: [],
                   animations: {
                    buttonColor.alpha = 0.0;
        },
                   completion: {finished in
                    buttonColor.alpha = 1.0;
                    if(index <= 4)
                    {
                        self.showSequence(index: index)
                    }

    })

}



func showSequence(index :  Int){


    if(index == 1){
      buttonAnimationChain(buttonColor: buttonBlue, index: index + 1)
    }
    if(index == 2){
      buttonAnimationChain(buttonColor: buttonBlue, index: index + 1)
    }
    if (index == 3){
      buttonAnimationChain(buttonColor: buttonBlue, index: index + 1)
    }
    if(index == 4){
      buttonAnimationChain(buttonColor: buttonBlue, index: index + 1)

    }//end of if statement

}
```

Call self.showSequence(index: 1) with index 1 for start the animation

Comment: The problem is a bit more complex. I need to animate the boxes in a certain sequence, rather than make a box flicker back and forth.

Comment: @RyanYang please check now please avoid any syntax error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling the animations one after another, without waiting for the first to end and UIView animations are asynchronous.

Maybe you should use a recursive function, call it with the first button, and when it ends call it again with the second button and so on.

Comment: I was thinking that too, but recursive functions create a new scope each time they are called, so if it animates long enough it will cause a memory leak that could crash your app.

Comment: @ScottyBlades Be sure to add a termination condition so it doesn't animate forever, also remember to add `[weak self] in` on each animation completion block, and finally, don't forget to use `weak` references for all the buttons. With those 3 checks you should have no problems with memory leaks, retain cycles or crashes at all.